# How to rotate and move a player and how to make a scrolling map?

Tags: python, pygame

I am coding a 2D game in python with the modules pygame, random, and math, and I am having some problems with the code. I have been looking all over the internet for help, but I have not been able to find the help I was looking for. I am able to rotate my players, but they lose quality and get blurry. Also, I need some way tom press w or up to move forward the direction the player is facing and press s or down to move backward the direction the player is facing, I know I have to use trigonometry and vectors, but how? And my scrolling map does not follow the two players based on their average x and y coordinates inside the display screen. And just so you know my zombies are invisible. This is not the full code, the relevant sections are the player classes, map and camera functions, rotate function, and other bits and pieces calling these functions:

```
import OpenGL
import panda3d
import pygame
import pyglet
import tkinter
import time
import random
import math

pygame.init()
display_width = 1250
display_height = 650
map_width = display_width*3
map_height = display_height*3

green = (0, 255, 0)
yellow = (255, 255, 0)
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

person_height = 113
person_width = 171
person2_width = 171
person2_height = 113


gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Wert')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

personImg = pygame.image.load('survivor-idle_shotgun_01.png').convert_alpha()
personImg2 = pygame.image.load('survivor-idle_shotgun_02.png').convert_alpha()
bulletImg = pygame.image.load('Untitled1.png').convert_alpha()
zombieImg = pygame.image.load('557a1e13af535e8351cb7056fde8589f.png').convert_alpha()
zombieImg1 = pygame.image.load('Untitled3.png').convert_alpha()

player_health = 100
player2_health = 100
x = display_width/2
y = display_height/2 - 56.5
ny = display_height/2 + 56.5
nx = display_width/2
#x = (0)
#y = (display_height * 0.37)
#ny = (display_height * 0.37)
#nx = (display_width * 0.87)
#thing_width = 100
#thing_height = 100





class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.original_image = personImg
        self.image = self.original_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.player_health = 100
        self.x_change = 0
        self.y_change = 0


    def update(self):
        self.x_change = 0
        self.y_change = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_w] and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/2, player2.rect.y + person2_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/4, player2.rect.y + person2_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width - 10, player2.rect.y + person2_height):
            self.y_change = -5
        if keystate[pygame.K_s] and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/2, player2.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/4, player2.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width - 10, player2.rect.y):
            self.y_change = 5
        #if keystate[pygame.K_d] and pygame.key.get_mods() and pygame.KMOD_LSHIFT and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height - 10):
            #self.x_change = 10
        #elif keystate[pygame.K_d] and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height - 10):
            #self.x_change = 5
        #if keystate[pygame.K_a] and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height - 10):
            #self.x_change = -5
        self.rect.x += self.x_change
        self.rect.y +=self.y_change
        if self.rect.right > map_width:
            self.rect.right = map_width
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.top < 50:
            self.rect.top = 50
        if self.rect.bottom > map_height:
            self.rect.bottom = map_height


    def shoot(self):
        bullet = Bullet1(self.rect.x, self.rect.y)
        all_sprites.add(bullet)
        bullets.add(bullet)






class Player2(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = personImg2
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = nx
        self.rect.y = ny
        self.player2_health = 100
        self.x_change1 = 0
        self.y_change1 = 0

    def update(self):
        self.x_change1 = 0
        self.y_change1 = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_UP] and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width/2, player.rect.y + person_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width/4, player.rect.y + person_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width - 10, player.rect.y + person_height):
            self.y_change1 = -5
        if keystate[pygame.K_DOWN] and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width/2, player.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width/4, player.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width - 10, player.rect.y):
            self.y_change1 = 5
        #if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT] and pygame.key.get_mods() and pygame.KMOD_RSHIFT and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width, player.rect.y + person_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width, player.rect.y + person_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width, player.rect.y + person_height - 10):
            #self.x_change1 = -10
        #elif keystate[pygame.K_LEFT] and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width, player.rect.y + person_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width, player.rect.y + person_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width, player.rect.y + person_height - 10):
            #self.x_change1 = -5
        #if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT] and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x, player.rect.y + person_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x, player.rect.y + person_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x, player.rect.y + person_height - 10):
            #self.x_change1 = 5
        self.rect.x += self.x_change1
        self.rect.y += self.y_change1
        if self.rect.right > map_width:
            self.rect.right = map_width
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.top < 50:
            self.rect.top = 50
        if self.rect.bottom > map_height:
            self.rect.bottom = map_height

    def shoot(self):
        bullet = Bullet(self.rect.x, self.rect.y)
        all_sprites.add(bullet)
        bullets1.add(bullet)

class Zombie(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = zombieImg
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(420, 830)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(0, display_height)
        self.x_change2 = 0
        self.y_change2 = 0

    def update(self):
        self.x_change2 = 0
        self.y_change2 = 0
        self.rect.x += self.x_change2
        self.rect.y += self.y_change2
        if self.rect.right > display_width:
            self.rect.right = display_width
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.top < 50:
            self.rect.top = 50
        if self.rect.bottom > display_height:
            self.rect.bottom = display_height

    def move_towards_player(self, player):
        dx, dy = self.rect.x - player.rect.x, self.rect.y - player.rect.y
        dist = math.hypot(dx, dy)
        dx, dy = dx / dist, dy / dist
        self.rect.x += dx * -1.1
        self.rect.y += dy * -1.1

class Zombie1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = zombieImg
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(420, 830)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(0, display_height)
        self.x_change2 = 0
        self.y_change2 = 0

    def update(self):
        self.x_change2 = 0
        self.y_change2 = 0
        self.rect.x += self.x_change2
        self.rect.y += self.y_change2
        if self.rect.right > display_width:
            self.rect.right = display_width
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.top < 50:
            self.rect.top = 50
        if self.rect.bottom > display_height:
            self.rect.bottom = display_height

    def move_towards_player(self, player):
        dx, dy = self.rect.x - player.rect.x, self.rect.y - player.rect.y
        dist = math.hypot(dx, dy)
        dx, dy = dx / dist, dy / dist
        self.rect.x += dx * -1.1
        self.rect.y += dy * -1.1

class Zombie2(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = zombieImg1
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(420, 830)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(0, display_height)
        self.x_change2 = 0
        self.y_change2 = 0

    def update(self):
        self.x_change2 = 0
        self.y_change2 = 0
        self.rect.x += self.x_change2
        self.rect.y += self.y_change2
        if self.rect.right > display_width:
            self.rect.right = display_width
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.top < 50:
            self.rect.top = 50
        if self.rect.bottom > display_height:
            self.rect.bottom = display_height

    def move_towards_player2(self, player2):
        dx, dy = self.rect.x - player2.rect.x, self.rect.y - player2.rect.y
        dist = math.hypot(dx, dy)
        dx, dy = dx / dist, dy / dist
        self.rect.x += dx * -1.1
        self.rect.y += dy * -1.1

class Zombie3(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = zombieImg1
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(420, 830)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(0, display_height)
        self.x_change2 = 0
        self.y_change2 = 0

    def update(self):
        self.x_change2 = 0
        self.y_change2 = 0
        self.rect.x += self.x_change2
        self.rect.y += self.y_change2
        if self.rect.right > display_width:
            self.rect.right = display_width
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.top < 50:
            self.rect.top = 50
        if self.rect.bottom > display_height:
            self.rect.bottom = display_height

    def move_towards_player2(self, player2):
        dx, dy = self.rect.x - player2.rect.x, self.rect.y - player2.rect.y
        dist = math.hypot(dx, dy)
        dx, dy = dx / dist, dy / dist
        self.rect.x += dx * -1.1
        self.rect.y += dy * -1.1

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
player2 = Player2()
bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullets1 = pygame.sprite.Group()
zombie = Zombie()
all_sprites.add(zombie)
zombie1 = Zombie1()
all_sprites.add(zombie1)
zombie2 = Zombie2()
all_sprites.add(zombie2)
zombie3 = Zombie3()
all_sprites.add(zombie3)

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 10))
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(gameDisplay)
        self.image.fill(black)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.x_change = -10


    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.x_change
        if self.rect.left > display_width:
            self.kill()
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.kill()

class Bullet1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 10))
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(gameDisplay)
        self.image.fill(black)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.x_change1 = 10

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.x_change1
        if self.rect.left > display_width:
            self.kill()
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.kill()

class Map(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, map_width, map_height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((map_width, map_height))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, map_width, map_height)
        self.image.fill(white)
        self.width = map_width
        self.height = map_height

class Camera(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, display_height, display_width):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((display_width, display_height))
        self.camera = pygame.Rect(0, 0, display_width, display_height)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, display_width, display_height)
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.image.fill(white)
        self.width = display_width
        self.height = display_height

    def apply(self, entity):
        return entity.rect.move(self.camera.topleft)

    def update(self):
        x = (-player.rect.x + -player2.rect.x)/2 + int(display_width/2)
        y = (-player.rect.y + -player2.rect.y)/2 + int(display_height/2)
        self.camera = pygame.Rect(x, y, self.width, self.height)



bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
players1 = pygame.sprite.Group()
players2 = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullet1 = Bullet1(x, y)
players1.add(player)
players2.add(player2)
map = Map(map_width, map_height)
camera = Camera(display_height, display_width)
all_sprites.add(map)
all_sprites.add(camera)
bullet = Bullet(x, y)
all_sprites.add(player)
all_sprites.add(player2)
zombies = pygame.sprite.Group()
zombies1 = pygame.sprite.Group()
zombies2 = pygame.sprite.Group()
zombies3 = pygame.sprite.Group()
zombies.add(zombie)
zombies1.add(zombie1)
zombies2.add(zombie2)
zombies3.add(zombie3)


def person(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(personImg, (x, y))



def person2(nx,ny):
    gameDisplay.blit(personImg2, (nx, ny))


#def boundary():
    #if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx + thing_width or x + person_width > thing_startx and x + person_width < thing_startx + thing_width:
    #if x > display_width - person_width or x < 0:

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))

        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("timesnewromanms",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def died():

    GameOver = True

    while GameOver:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        redrawgame()
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("timesnewromanms", 115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Player 2 wins", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2), (display_height / 2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("Play Again", 500, 400, 100, 50, blue, blue, game_loop)
        button("Quit", 700, 400, 100, 50, red, red, quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

def died1():


    GameOver = True

    while GameOver:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        redrawgame()
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("timesnewromanms", 115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Player 1 wins", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2), (display_height / 2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("Play Again", 500, 400, 100, 50, blue, blue, game_loop)
        button("Quit", 700, 400, 100, 50, red, red, quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

def rotate():
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_a]:
                angle = 5
                orig_rect = player.image.get_rect()
                player.image = pygame.transform.rotate(player.image, angle)
                rot_rect = orig_rect.copy()
                rot_rect.center = player.image.get_rect().center
                player.image = player.image.subsurface(rot_rect).copy()
                return player.image
        elif keystate[pygame.K_d]:
                angle = -5
                orig_rect = player.image.get_rect()
                player.image = pygame.transform.rotate(player.image, angle)
                rot_rect = orig_rect.copy()
                rot_rect.center = player.image.get_rect().center
                player.image = player.image.subsurface(rot_rect).copy()
                return player.image
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                angle = 5
                orig_rect = player2.image.get_rect()
                player2.image = pygame.transform.rotate(player2.image, angle)
                rot_rect = orig_rect.copy()
                rot_rect.center = player2.image.get_rect().center
                player2.image = player2.image.subsurface(rot_rect).copy()
                return player2.image
        elif keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                angle = -5
                orig_rect = player2.image.get_rect()
                player2.image = pygame.transform.rotate(player2.image, angle)
                rot_rect = orig_rect.copy()
                rot_rect.center = player2.image.get_rect().center
                player2.image = player2.image.subsurface(rot_rect).copy()
                return player2.image
```

Comment: One question at a time please.

Comment: Woah buddy! Try to pare this down into something we can parse through. If you give us everything all at once, your chances of getting an (some) answer(s) are very low! See the help for how to ask questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is the purpose of the three identical(?) `zombie` classes? This could easily be a single class with some kind of variant-type passed during initialisation if they look or act a little differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a bitmap is rotated, unless it's to a 90 degree (or multiple) angle, a bit of quality is lost.

The rotation code takes the current player bitmap and rotates it, over and over.  Every rotation is dropping some quality.

It would be a better approach to keep track of the rotation total, and then rotate an original copy of the bitmap in a single operation.

For example, the `rotate()` function goes in 5 degree intervals.

```
def newRotate():
    player.modifyRotation(5)
    player.image = player.original_image.copy()
    player.image = pygame.transform.rotate( player.image, player.getRotation() )
    ...
```

Where `modifyRotation()` might be something like:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.original_image = personImg2
        self.image = self.original_image.copy()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.angle = 0
        ...

    def modifyRotation(self, degrees):
        self.angle += degrees

    def getRotation(self):
        return self.angle
```

The OP's code mixes up accesses and changes to th ePlayer Class member variables.  Perhaps it would be better if the Player class had it's own `rotate()` function that handled all these operations internally.

Of course another approach, assuming a constant set of 5 degree increments, is to pre-rotate all the player bitmaps at the start.  I expect this would be a little more efficient too.  Bitmap rotation is computationally expensive.